# Interactive sorting to matrix report in reporting services 2005

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

i created a matrix report that have 2 rows and 6 columns.
picture 1 (see album picture in the bottom)

i want so active a interactive sort on the last columns that named 'Matrix1_ObjName'.

to do so i clicked right click on the field and go to properties > interactive sort.
than i entered the parameters like in the picture 2 (see album picture in the bottom).

i have done some research and the closes answer was posted on this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/6f014928-7e12-4de1-908d-45de3860849b)

the interactive sort doesn't work.

to be clear i want that the LoginName column will be sorted by the grade that shown in the objName row.
sea picture 3 (see album picture in the bottom)

[album pictures](https://picasaweb.google.com/adi.silagy/CMwOOK?authkey=Gv1sRgCOTdnd6MnbvEEw&feat=directlink)

thanks to all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use interactive sort.  When I want to be able to change sorting behavior, I do it with a parameter.  Create a new report parameter and specify values.  Use something descriptive for the labels, then I use integers beginning at zero for the values.  After the param is set up right click on a field in report design and go to `Row Group` then `Group Properties`.  Select `Sorting` from the menu and build an expression with an if statement similar to this:

`=IIf(Parameters!sort.Value=0,Fields!First_Sort.Value,Fields!Second_Sort.Value)`

Might help you.